# Single Ciphertext which can decrypt with multiple keys

Tags: encryption, public-key, symmetric

Say we have a public key system where we have 2 users, Alice, and Bob each has a public and private key. We also have a publicly available server which stores a message.

I want to encrypt this message (M) for Alice and Bob only once. such that either Alice or Bob can decrypt the message with their private key.

The easy and well-studied way to do this is to generate a random symmetric key and encrypt the message with that key, then I can encrypt a small message (SM) For Alice and Bob with their public keys which gives them the symmetric key, with this they can now both decrypt the Message M available on the server.

However is there any known way that I can encrypt the message M, where both Alice and Bob can decrypt M without needing an additional symmetric key? I have looked briefly into double trapdoor encryption and Broadcast encryption but I don't think these schemes suit the purpose?

TL;DR One Ciphertext that can be decrypted by multiple Public, Private keypairs, without deriving an additional symmetric key

Comment: I‘d say it’s not possible because it would require the multiple decryption keys to have sone kind of mathematical relation which would make them vulnerable to an attack. Any specific reason for not using the common way you already described?

Comment: So in other words, you're asking about equivalent keys in asymmetric crypto?

Comment: @not2savvy Honestly its just for a personal project im doing where i am looking for ways to reduce the communication overhead and this would be a small optimization.

I thought this too, if the two keys have a relationship how much weaker is that system,do you think i can increase the size of the keys to makeup for that weakness?

Comment: @forest i cant say i'm familiar with the idea of equivalent keys, although after a little googling i think thats the jist of it

Comment: Do the two recipients have independently-generated private keys, or do they generate them together?

Comment: @forest they would be independently generated

Comment: @Juam12 I don’t think so because it doesn’t change the connection between the keys. But I am not a crypto expert. However, if you want to reduce communication overhead, I‘d say hybrid encryption, as used in S/MIME or PGP, is your best option.

Comment: I was thinking that in the one-time-pad scheme it is totally possible to have multiple identical ciphertexts that have differing underlying plaintext and keys, but you couldn't have two different keys that decode the same plaintext, given the identical ciphertext unless the ciphertext was all zeroes, which would make the plain text message identical to the key. Must the scheme include public-private key pairs?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid the additional symmetric key?  Essentially every public-key encryption scheme for bits uses a combination of fancy math like RSA and a bog-standard symmetric authenticated cipher like AES-GCM (or is broken, like OpenPGP for a long time and S/MIME still last I checked).  If it is to reduce communication bandwidth costs, can you lay out exactly what your communication bandwidth budget is?

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage the question is more theoretical, i wont be applying this to a production system, i'm interested in the possibilities and if anyone has a novel solution.

Comment: What is the theoretical motivation for this?  That is, why do you care that there be fancy math like $x \mapsto x^3 \bmod pq$ for large primes $p$ and $q$ _but not_ something like AES or ChaCha or Poly1305 involved?

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage There is no motivation, i'm just interested if anyone has a novel way to do this that i haven't thought of. I mentioned in my question the clear way to solve this problem, but i'm interested in different (potentially less secure) approaches

Comment: OK, but what are the actual constraints?  Is ‘avoid AES and ChaCha and Poly1305’ the real constraint, or what?

Comment: Have you looked into Identity Based Encryption? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID-based_encryption

Comment: Modern public-key encryption (that is, public-key encryption with strong a security argument) is hybrid, including RSA even for small messages: RSAES-OAEP internaly uses a PRF built from a hash, which is essentially symmetric crypto. Thus the question is ill-formulated, and I vote to close it as unclear (the nearest available match).

Comment: @HenrickHellström thats an interesting scheme the the key issue seems to be the PKG which must be trusted. In the above scenario i would have the keypairs for both Alice and Bob before i needed to encrypt, so i would just need a way to encrypt so that they can both decrypt, while only creating a single ciphertext

Answer (score 2):

One trivial solution is to let the message be:
$$M = (c_{\text{Alice}}, c_{\text{Bob}}) = (Enc_{k_{pub,A}}(m), Enc_{k_{pub,B}}(m))$$
Whether this counts as a "single message" or not is difficult to say.
Even if it does, it has the (unfortunate) property that Alice/Bob can't distinguish between:
$$M = (Enc_{k_{pub,A}}(m), Enc_{k_{pub,B}}(m)),\quad M' = (Enc_{k_{pub,A}}(m), Enc_{k_{pub,B}}(m'))$$
for $m'\neq m$ (so an adversary could "encrypt" something different to each of them, and provided the underlying scheme is CPA secure neither Alice nor Bob will be able to detect the adversarial behavior).

If you want to reduce the communication overhead of your scheme, hybrid encryption (encrypting the private key under both public keys) is likely the best choice, because after this initial "setup" phase you can switch to solely symmetric crypto under this new key.
Symmetric crypto tends to have a lower communication overhead than asymmetric crypto (the term to look at here is the "rate" of the encryption scheme).

That all being said, it's unclear precisely what your threat model is, and even hybrid encryption could easily allow for an adversary to encrypt different keys under Alice/Bob's public keys (so they initially disagree on their secret keys).
How this could be leveraged to mount a larger attack I don't know, but without fixing a particular threat model it's difficult to discuss what security would even mean.

Comment: Yes, this works and will satisfy the single message constraint, however it looks like have two ciphertexts here. It would be nicer if we can have a single ciphertext which two private keys can decrypt, without having to send additional messages.